# low pass filter

Tags: filters

I am new to DSP, I'm trying to implement a low pass filter in a microcontroller and I'm looking for examples on the internet.

One of the simplest low pass filter (as its title says) is [this](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Simplest_Lowpass_Filter_I.html).
But I don't understand how is this a low pass filter? All that I see is just an equation

```
y = 2x - 1
```

I made a simple example on google sheets and it gave me the same triangle signal with just higher amplitude. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The equation you probably refer to is

$$y[n]=x[n]+x[n-1]\tag{1}$$

(which is not equivalent to $y[n]=x[n]+x[n]-1$).

The integer $n$ is the time index, so from in Eq. $(1)$ the output is computed as the sum of the current and the previous input values. This is, up to scaling, equivalent to a two-point averaging operation. This low pass filter is really quite simple but it also doesn't really do much.

Another very simple but better low pass filter is

$$y[n]=\alpha x[n]+(1-\alpha)y[n-1]\tag{2}$$

which is called an [exponentially weighted moving average filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average). There are a lot of questions about that type of filter on this site, e.g. [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/28308/4298), [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/51470/4298), [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46278/4298), and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/54086/4298).